# Get number of seconds until the start of the next hour

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

- I'm currently using a REST API that only allows 1000 queries per hour
- Once the 1000 queries are used up, you then have to wait until the beginning of the next hour for the counter to be reset
- My aim is to determine the number of seconds that I have to wait until the start of the next hour
- I'm currently using the `time.sleep` method to put the script to sleep until the start of the next hour

I've put together a rather crude solution as follows using the `datetime` library  (adding two minutes to be safe)

```
import datetime

# Determine the seconds until the next hour (add 2 minutes to be safe)
now = datetime.datetime.now()
next_hour = datetime.datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour + 1, 2)
sleep_seconds = (next_hour - now).seconds

# Put the execution to sleep for a while
print("Sleeping for {0} minutes...".format(sleep_seconds // 60))
time.sleep(sleep_seconds)
```

This script does work but is unreliable when the next hour is the start of the next day.

- `datetime` expects hour values between `0..23`
- If the
  `datetime.datetime.now()` method returned `23` the method would fail
  if you pass `24` to the `datetime` object
- It would also be unreliable if the next day crossed into the next month or year as well.

Could someone suggest a better solution that would account for these wrap around issues?

Comment: You should be able to use `datetime.datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1)`.

Comment: Why do you want your Api to behave like that?

Comment: @erip That solution would simply add 1 hour to the `datetime` object returned by `now()` instead of producing a `datetime` object for the start of the next hour

Comment: @OlivierMelançon This isn't an API that I've created, it is an API that I need to query

Comment: Yes, there's more work to be done... but that handles rollover.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Think `datetime.timedelta` will help you in this case. Something like this:

```
import datetime

delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
now = datetime.datetime.now()
next_hour = (now + delta).replace(microsecond=0, second=0, minute=2)

wait_seconds = (next_hour - now).seconds
```

The `replace` should work to round you down to the next hour.

Comment: This will of course return the next hour but what about producing a `datetime` object  that goes to the next day?

Comment: Great. The `replace` method worked for me, was able to round off the next hour datetime to get the correct number of seconds